# How to change "code ," in bash to "code ."

Tags: bash, terminal, zsh

I'm trying to change `code ,` to `code .` in bash, but I am getting a bunch of errors. This should work.

```
code() {
  if [[ $1 == ,]];
  then
    code .
  else
    code $1
  fi
  return 1
}
```

It gives me parse error because of the semi colon

if I take the semi colon out, it gives me condition expected: $1

if I add quotes to the `,` and add the semi colon back in, if i get  parse error near `;'

if I keep the quotes and remove the semi colon I get condition expected: $1

if I remove the semi colon and escape the `,` it literally just closes the terminal window.

what is going on here? all the documentaion online syas this should work.

Comment: You need a space between `,` and  `]]`.

Comment: Paste your code into shellcheck.net.

Comment: I pasted it in shellcheck.net and added the space and I'm getting  this error:

    Line 1:
    code() {
    ^-- SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.
 
    Line 6:
        code $1
             ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Comment: You are asking specifically about Bash; why is this also tagged [tag:zsh]?

Comment: Hey tripleeee what was the duplicate that you found? can you link to it?

Comment: @tripleee you marked as duplicate but you didn't have an answer...

Comment: Did you read the answers to the linked duplicate question? Which part of them are you having trouble understanding or applying? If you can [edit] this question to make clear that it is not a duplicate, we can vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash        # added shebang, bash since you have [[
code() {
  if [[ $1 == , ]] # removed the ; and added a space after ,
  then
    echo then      # added this
    code .
  else
    echo else      # and this
    code $1
  fi
  return 1
}

code $1
```

Run it:

```
$ bash foo.sh , | head -3
then
else
else
$ bash foo.sh . | head -3
else
else
else
```